# Default values in multiple Form::select in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I use Laravel 5.4 with Collective\Html package.

I try to build a form with multiple select element and set a default values for it.

My form.blade.php file

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'', 'method'=>'GET']) !!}

    {!! Form::select(
        "fruits[]",
        [1=>"apple", 2=>"peer", 3=>"banana"],
        [1, 3],
        ["multiple"=>true]
        );
    !!}

    ...

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This code works fine and I see multi-line select element with selected first and third lines.

But if I send to this page GET data through url like `/form?fruits[]=2&fruits[]=3` pre-selected valued are not available any more.

As far as I understand, the reason is in `Collective\Html\FormBuilder` class. Beginning from v5.2 following code was added to the `getValueAttribute()` method (lines 1163-1166 at v.5.4):

```
$request = $this->request($name);
if (!is_null($request)) {
    return $request;
}
```

This code returns and overrides default values from Form::select() and takes needed values from the request. It is nice, but looks like developers do not have a full control under `select` element after this update.

After some manipulations in the `FormBuilder` class, default values are sent to the `getSelectedValue()` method, which set 'selected' attribute for needed `option`s in `select` element (lines 762-764)

```
if (is_array($selected)) {
    return in_array($value, $selected, true) ? 'selected' : null;
//--------------------------------------^-----------------
//-------------------------------problem origin-----------
}
```

Here `in_array` looks for option value (`$value`) in default values from url (`$selected`). As far values from url are strings and `$value` is integer `FormBuilder` does not find default options at all.

How to set default values without editing source class? Should I override `HtmlServiceProvider`, `HtmlBuilder` and `FormBuilder` classes just to remove `true` parameter?

Maybe there is some more native way to set default values?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: you are able to get this data like `?fruits%5B%5D=1&fruits%5B%5D=2&submit=submit`

Comment: @ Dhaval Purohit. Thank you for the comment. I have the same result, as modern browsers update fruits%5B%5D to fruits[] automatically. Problem is not related to the url view.

Comment: so what is the problem at all can you explain?

Comment: Problem is the old selected values are not being set. I think overriding classes is not the best way to solve the problem

Comment: there is no need to override the class.
just tell me how the old selected values is coming ? is it from the database or from the submitting the form ?

Comment: Form submits data to the same page with GET method, so old parameters are taken from the url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147129/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-lubart).

Comment: check the chat i have posted all code and it is working like a charm

Comment: thank you for your example, I have left my one in the chat